# Getting Items from an Orchard CMS Custom Content Type object

Tags: c#, orchardcms

We've created a custom Type in orchard through the Admin page, it has fields on it. How can I get access to those fields in a module?

The way I can find to do it is:

```
   dynamic firstCourse = _contentManager.Query().ForType("Course").List().First();
   var fields = firstCourse.Parts[5].Fields as List<ContentField>;
```

This is can't be the right solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
dynamic firstCourse = _contentManager.Query("Course").List().First();
var myField = firstCourse.Course.MyField as WhateverTypeTheFieldIs;
```

This should do the trick to get the field called "MyField" but your question is unclear about what exactly you're trying to do. If you're trying to get the list of all fields, then this should work, I think:

```
var fields = firstCourse.Course.Fields as IEnumerable<ContentField>;
```

(also, you are more likely to get a good answer if you don't insult the people most likely to provide it. The documentation is open source, so go and fix it.)

Comment: I wrote that after spending close to 2 hours trying to figure this out, after watching a course video I don't think this is the Orchard way, I think I'm supposed to use DataMigrations when I need easier programmatic access to the objects. I'll edit the obviously aggravated wording but the point stands, the docs leave a lot to be desired from a dev standpoint, I'll contribute some in a week when I can speak Orchard a little better.

(I wasn't insulting the people, I was insulting the documentation, a la critique the code not the coder)

Comment: This isn't working. If I do:

`dynamic non = _contentManager.New("Nominee");`
`var myField = non.PersonalDetails.FirstName as string;`

PersonalDetails is a part, Nominee is the ContentType and FirstName is a field. I get "'Orchard.ContentManagement.ContentItem' does not contain a definition for 'PersonalDetails'"

Comment: A migration? What for? I'm struggling to see what migrations could possibly have to do with your question. Now you're asking a different question. If the content item is new, it may not have all the parts and fields yet before you Create it. In this case the part is not yet there. Finally, thanks for updating the question, but don't be surprised if people feel insulted when you insult their work. Just saying.